# Default method to extend existing JDK interfaces

Tags: java, java-8

Am I able to use default methods to extend existing JDK interfaces like `List` to add an extra  method to anything that implements it?

If so, is there a simple example anywhere?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that; that seems like a very worrisome idea.

Comment: Once a type is compiled, there is no way to modify it. As such, you can't add functionality in the way you are describing.

Comment: No. Java does not support [Extension Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDK code, as with any other piece of compiled code, cannot be modified. So, any existing type (`List` or other) cannot change its behavior via the addition of a method, or of any other mechanism.

The only option is to just extend the classes you want to modify (if they are not declared as `final` - e.g., `String` cannot be extended) and change the functionality there. Obviously, any extended class also has the type of all its parents so, for example, an `ExtendedList` class is also a `List`, assuming its declaration is something like

```
public class ExtendedList<E> extends List<E>
{
    ...
}
```

What you are asking is probably the functionality of **Extension Methods**, as already mentioned in a comment above, which is a rather cool feature not supported by `Java`. Other languages, such as `C#`, offer such support.

Comment: You are welcome. The solution presented by dkatzel is also interesting and closer to what you originally asked, albeit the one you chose is simpler and "Java only". :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own *Extension Methods* to add methods to JDK classes but not in Java but by using other JVM languages like Groovy.

here is a Groovy tutorial on how to add Extension methods

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+an+extension+module

Basically, you just have to make a new class with a static method you want to add.  The first parameter of this method is the object you want to add the method to and any other parameters are the parameters in your method

```
public class MyExtension{
     public static String myMethod(List list, /*  other params here*/){
              //do stuff

     }
}
```

Then you need to add a module descriptor file name `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` into the `META-INF/services` directory with the following contents:

```
moduleName=your-module-name
moduleVersion=your-module-version
extensionClasses=your-extension-full-classname
staticExtensionClasses= other-extension-class-for-static-methods
```

And that's it

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to add a new default method to interfaces you don't yourself control.